# Rearrange each row of a 2d numpy array with an index for each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array x

```
x = np.array([[6,7,8],                                             
              [9,10,11]])
```

and I want to rearrange each row of the array x with an index

```
index = np.array([[2,0,1],                                                  
                  [1,2,0]])
```

such that

```
result[i,:] = x[i,index[i,:]]

result = np.array([[8,6,7],                                                  
                  [10,11,9]])
```

I have a large array x so I dont want to do this with a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can broadcast a range of numbers from `0` to the shape of your array, and index your columns the same way you have now:

```
x[np.arange(x.shape[0])[:, None], index]
```

```
array([[ 8,  6,  7],
       [10, 11,  9]])
```